# git svn dcommit fails with "Incomplete data: Delta source ended unexpectedly"

Tags: git, git-svn, dcommit

I'm working with a remote team using an SVN repository. Mostly because of the high latency I experienced when contacting the repository, I decided to use git-svn. Everything is working great until I attempt to dcommit.

I have several local commits, and only one of them I want to push to SVN. I did `git rebase -i HEAD~4` to mark the commit I needed for editing. `git svn dcommit -n` confirms that this is the only revision which will be committed.

However, running `git svn dcommit` gives the error

```
Incomplete data: Delta source ended unexpectedly
```

from line 572 of `git-svn` which is

```
if (!SVN::Git::Editor->new(\%ed_opts)->apply_diff) {
```

I'm not sure if committing via SVN directly works yet as it takes hours to checkout the repository (even just the portion I'm interested in) so I can attempt a commit.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what tool are you using? I mean which flavour of git (msysgit, git in cygwin, etc) and also are you using any git GUI tool?

Comment: No GUI. I'm using the version of git installed by the Ubuntu package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end result ended up being a permissions issue with the remote SVN server. I re-initialized my git-svn repository and double-checked my path to the server and all seems to be well now. IIRC, the issue was HTTP vs. HTTPS. i.e., I could checkout the repository over HTTP, but not commit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a bit of [googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=SVN%20Incomplete%20data%3a%20Delta%20source%20ended%20unexpectedly), the problem also occurs in pure SVN.

Check which version of SVN you are using with `git svn --version` - perhaps an upgrade will help. Updating to the latest version of git could help as well.

Comment: I'm running the latest of git and SVN, but unfortunately I have no control over the remote SVN server.